# Access printer using SQL Server Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, printing

How can I access my printer using SQL Server Stored Procedure?

Comment: Why would you do that ? 
I think it is not good practice. It is the program that executes your stored procedure that might decide to print or not the results it receives from it, not the procedure itself...

Comment: I think it's impossible. The only way it can be done is use "assembly". But in this case you need to write code for printing in another language (C# etc) and put it in DLL. DLL can be attached to SQL Server by Create Assembly statement.

Comment: Please check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193638/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-send-a-query-directly-to-a-physical-printer .

Answer (score 1):

> Stored procedures are great for manipulating data, but they are very
>   limited when it comes to interacting with system resources outside the
>   database. Even writing to a file can be awkward, never mind printing.

If still you want to print the document from Stored Procedure, you can follow this steps from this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17531/How-to-Print-a-Document-from-SQL-Stored-Procedure)

**Step 1:**
At first, let's build a simple VB DLL (ActiveX component) that would handle the actual printing using Microsoft Word. In ActiveX component, add a method that would print a document using Microsoft Word:

```
Public Sub PrintDocumentFromWord(ByVal DocumentFileName As String)

    On Error GoTo Err_Error

    Dim MethodName As String
    MethodName = ".PrintWebDocumentFromWord()"

    Dim strMessage As String

    Dim blnResult As Boolean

    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    'Dim objWord As Object
    'Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Const wdAlertsNone = 0
    objWord.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

    'objWord.Activate
    'objWord.PrintOut FileName:=DocumentFileName
    Dim objDocument As Word.Document

    Set objDocument = objWord.Documents.Open(DocumentFileName)

    objDocument.Activate

    objDocument.PrintOut

    objDocument.Close

    objWord.Quit

Exit_Procedure:
    Set objDocument = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing

    Exit Sub

Err_Error:

    'handle error here
    Call HandleError("PrintWebDocument", ApplicationName, MethodName, VBA.Error)

    If Not objWord Is Nothing Then
        objWord.Quit
    End If

    Resume Exit_Procedure

End Sub
```

Compile and build ActiveX component. ActiveX component will reside on the same machine where SQL Server instance is running.

**Step 2:** Next, create a stored procedure that calls ActiveX component and passes file name of the document to be printed:

```
CREATE procedure sp_Print_Letter_File
(
    @file_name varchar(333)
    ,@debug_mode char(1)=''
)
as
    set nocount on

    declare @return int

    declare @print_document int
    declare @hr int
    declare @src varchar(255), @desc varchar(255)

    exec @hr = master.dbo.sp_OACreate 'PrintDocument.clsPrintDocument', _
    @print_document OUT
    if @hr <> 0    -- error creating instance!
    begin
           exec master.dbo.sp_OAGetErrorInfo  @print_document, @src out, @desc out
        select 'Creating Instance', hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), _
        source=@src, description=@desc
        set @return = -1
        goto error
    end

if @debug_mode<>''
    print '1. created'

    exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @print_document, 'PrintDocumentFromWord',_
    null,@file_name, @debug_mode
    if @hr <> 0
    begin
           exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @print_document, @src OUT, @desc OUT
        select 'Call to Method', hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), _
    Source=@src, Description=@desc

        exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @print_document
        if @hr <> 0
        begin
            exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @print_document, @src out, @desc out
            select 'Destroing Instance',hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), _
        source=@src, description=@desc
            --return
        end
        set @return = -2
        goto error

    end

if @debug_mode<>''
    print '2. send to object'

error:

    exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @print_document
    if @hr <> 0
    begin
        exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @print_document, @src out, @desc out
        select 'Destroing Instance',hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), _
        source=@src, description=@desc
        set @return = -3
    end

if @debug_mode<>''
    print '3. done!'

set nocount off

GO
```

And that's it. Don't forget to register your ActiveX component (I usually do it with Component Services MMC snap-in).